# How to create a custom coder?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a custom coder [AvroDeterministicCoder](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/fce3cd22650ec843d9194628d72feb1c8d9beae5/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/AvroDeterministicCoder.java?at=master) which is based on [AvroCoder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/6ad521097f50d6390ba99489d0dffb87c9991715/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java) but returns true for isDeterministic.

In my [example Dataflow](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/fce3cd22650ec843d9194628d72feb1c8d9beae5/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/AvroKeyExample.java?at=master) I register this coder for all my PCollections. However, when I run my [test](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/fce3cd22650ec843d9194628d72feb1c8d9beae5/dataflow/src/test/java/dataflow/AvroKeyExampleTest.java?at=master) it ends up throwing an exception:
`the key coder must be deterministic for grouping.`

Using my debugger, I can tell that its using the coder AvroCoder.

In [AvroDeterministicCoder](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/fce3cd22650ec843d9194628d72feb1c8d9beae5/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/AvroDeterministicCoder.java?at=master) do I need to add code to cause [AvroDeterministicCoder](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/fce3cd22650ec843d9194628d72feb1c8d9beae5/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/AvroDeterministicCoder.java?at=master) to be deserialized as [AvroDeterministicCoder](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/fce3cd22650ec843d9194628d72feb1c8d9beae5/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/AvroDeterministicCoder.java?at=master)  and not as an AvroCoder?

Comment: I think I forgot to override the of methods so its returning an AvroCoder.

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug in my code; I needed to override the various `of` methods to return type AvroDeterministicCoder.

Here's the working code: [AvroDeterministicCoder](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/3fc7ae6d353fd8457d757eac72322ec2f768a6e5/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/AvroDeterministicCoder.java?at=master).